# Git: How to undo local commits and addition of file?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I mistakenly added files to `master` and committed too. Otherwise I had to do it in a branch `feature_x`

Now I know there are commands like `git reset`. My issue is, if I reset things, will it undo my code too or just undo files and commit in `master`?

How do I avoid resetting things without losing code?

**Update**

Code has not been pushed on remote yet. When I tried it gave error:

`error: src refspec feature_x does not match any.`

Comment: Have you pushed the commit to a public repo?

Comment: @joran not yet as it gave error `error: src refspec feature_x does not match any`

Comment: Create new branch `feature_x` in your local, switch to this branch, then push to remote repository

Comment: branch already exists on bitbucket.. I just not being able to checkout

Comment: The error `src refspec feature_x does not match any` probably means that the branch `feature_x` doesn't exist locally. To get it from the remote, `git fetch && git checkout -b feature_x origin/feature_x`. (On newer git versions, you can shorten this to `git fetch && git checkout feature_x`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are currently on the master branch with the accidental commits X, Y and Z like this:

```
A - B - C - X - Y - Z  <- master
```

Now you can create a new branch where you currently are using

```
git branch feature-x
```

The feature-x branch will point to the same commit as the master branch, making it safe to reset the master branch to the earlier version:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3    # Move master branch 3 commits back
```

You now have this

```
          X - Y - Z  <- feature-x
         /
A - B - C  <- master
```

Now you can checkout the feature-x branch again:

```
git checkout feature-x
```

Comment: Maybe I am finally learning how to read these git branch diagrams. In  any case this was clear.

Comment: This helped me to roll back 1 step when my code was stable before pulling what is in master.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

If I am not sure that I won't to delete my commits or not.

It will give you back to staging phase.

Comment: What I want, undo multiple `git add`s and commits into `master` and push changes to branch `feature_x`

Comment: may be you can use `git cherry-pick`

Comment: Tell me one thing; if I am standing on `master` and ran `git add`. Were they added in `master` node and `git push origin feature_x` will not let send those committed files to `feature_x`?

Comment: @Volatil3 `git add` adds files to the index a.k.a. staging area. The added changes only become a commit / revision when you commit them with `git commit`. What branch they will be committed to depends on the branch checked out during `git commit`, rather than on the branch checked out during `git add`. If you push a branch to a remote, only its commits will be pushed, not any added-but-not-yet-commited changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well I do not know the command line way of the top of my head, but most git clients have a button called discard. in sourcetree this is the 3th button on your band, this will discard any local changes, if you already commited the changes please revert them.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, you have commits on the `master` branch that you don't want on the `master` branch, but that you still want to preserve unchanged. Instead of on `master`, you want these commits on branch `feature_x`. I assume the commits you want on `feature_x` instead of on `master` are the last commits on `master`, thus there are no commits you want to keep on `master` between them.

It is important to know here that in git, it **is not** an intrinsic property of a commit on what branch it was created. Branches are just named pointers (similar to tags, in that way) referring to a specific revision, which (unlike tags) move automatically to a new revision if it is committed while that branch is the checked out branch.

Thus,

## If branch `feature_x` doesn't exist yet

1. If you have uncommitted changes (already added to index or not) that you want to preserve, temporarily persist them and get them out of the way with

   ```sh
   git stash
   ```
2. Go to the `master` branch

   ```sh
   git checkout master
   ```
3. Create branch `feature_x` pointing to the same commit as `master` still does

   ```sh
   git branch feature_x
   ```

   (other than `git checkout -b feature_x`, this will keep `master` checked out instead of switching to the newly created `feature_x`)
4. Before proceeding, make sure that

   - none of the above commands have failed or yielded any unexpected output
   - `master` is still the checked out branch
5. Now, let's move the `master` branch to the **last** commit you want to be on `master`.

   If that's the commit that bitbucket's `master` points to and you have your bitbucket repository as the remote `origin` in your local repository (find out with `git remote -v`) then do this as follows:

   - Make sure your local repositories knowledge about the remote is up-to-date:

     ```sh
     git fetch
     ```
   - Move the currently checked out branch (your local `master` branch) to the commit that the remote `master` branch is pointing to:

     ```sh
     git reset --hard origin/master
     ```

   If however, before the commits you don't want on `master`, there are some more commits on `master` that you want to keep on `master`, but that are not yet present on your bitbucket repository, then it might be easier to navigate backwards from your local current `master` branch. Say, you want to not have the last 5 commits on `master` not to be there, and they are purely linear (no merges amongst them), you can

   ```sh
   git reset --hard master~5
   ```

   If the situation is more complicated than that (e.g., there are merges in the part of history you don't want on master), it'll be easier to find out the ID (sha1 hash) of the last commit you want on master with help of a graphical tool and then move `master to that

   ```sh
   git reset --hard <commit id>
   ```

   e.g., if the commit ID is `a1b2c3d4`

   ```sh
   git reset --hard a1b2c3d4
   ```

## If branch `feature_x` already exists ...

### ... and points to an ancestor of `master`

Proceed as above, but between steps 1 and 2 (i.e., before you check out `master`), move `feature_x` forward to current `master` with

```sh
git checkout feature_x
git merge --ff-only master
```

and skip step 3 (creating branch `feature_x`).

### ... and has commits on it that aren't on `master`

but that you want to keep on `feature_x` together with the commits in question from `master`, then you have several possibilities.

The easiest and safest is to merge the commits from `master` into `feature_x`, again between steps 1 and 2 (i.e., before you check out `master`):

```sh
git checkout feature_x
git merge master  # You might want to modify the suggested commit message,
                  # as 'merge master into feature_x' will be confusing when
                  # those commits won't be ancestors of 'master' later on.
```

Then again proceed as above from step 2, skipping step 3.

If you want a linear history on `feature_x`, there's the alternatives of rebasing the commits from master on top of the commits on `feature_x` (so it will be as if you had committed them on `feature_x` to begin with **after** the commits already there) or to rebase the commits from `feature_x` on top of the commits on `master` (so it will be as if the commits previously on master had been committed on `feature_x` to begin with even **before** the commits already there). **If the linear history isn't a must, I'd recommend against both these alternatives**, as rebasing can become a bit hairy and requires very good understanding of git. If you pursue one of them anyway, make sure you know what you're doing (read the help pages for the commands you use) and that you're doing it right (make sure you've understood those help pages and try to avoid mistypings). Especially when rebasing for the first time (but also later), it might be worth making a local clone of your repository so you have a backup if stuff goes wrong.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to push your code from a different branch, you don't need to revert your commits.

- Just pull master branch and create new branch from master
- After that push your branch and create a merge request
- Merge your code
- Pull master to local

It should work.

Comment: It's neither clear how to perform these steps nor what they should achieve in the scenario of the question.

Comment: Initial problem was "i committed my changes to master branch, but i needed to commit it to another branch". So i thought he forgot to create a new branch before commit and he cannot send changes to origin. Because usually you can't directly push to master(for the sake of codes). And i said that he doesn't need to revert anything. All he needs to do is create a new branch from local master and push that new branch which contains all changes he did. After merging that new branch to master, problem will be solved.